# Dual Space Isomorphic to Quotient Space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a (not necessarily finite-dimensional) linear space $X$. Show that $Y'$ (the dual of $Y$) is isomorphic to $X'/Y^{\perp}$.

First, I think there is a problem with the question. Since there is no mention of $X$ being normed, I think $Y^{\perp}$ should be $Y^0$, then annihilator of $Y$. Do you agree?

Suppose that correction is needed. Since $Y\subseteq X$, define the embedding $i:Y\to X$. Then the dual map is $i^{\times}:X'\to Y'$. The kernel of this map is:

$\begin{align}
\text{null}(i^{\times})&=\{f\in X': i^{\times}(f)=0\}\\
&=\{f\in X': f\circ i=0\}\\
&=\{f\in X': f(i(y))=0 \ \forall y\in Y\}\\
&=\{f\in X': f(y)=0 \ \forall y\in Y\}\\
&=Y^0
\end{align}$

Hence, the map $\phi:X'/\text{null}(i^{\times})\to Y'$, given by $\phi(x+\text{null}(i^{\times}))=i^{\times}(x)$ is isomorphic onto its image. But $\text{Im}(\phi)=\text{Im}(i^{\times})=Y'$. Hence, $X'/\text{null}(i^{\times})=X'/Y^0\cong Y'$.

Does this look correct?

Comment: Notations vary, but if $Y$ is a subspace of a linear space $X$, $Y^\perp$ is often used to denote the annihilator of $Y$.

Comment: I see. I've only seen $Y^{\perp}$ for orthogonal complement, but that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @Robert Israel. Moreover, your proof looks almost correct. You need to prove that $\mathrm{Im}(i^{\times})=Y'$

Comment: @paf Yes, I left that part out because I thought it was the most straightforward :)